# Performance of large transactions and concurrency?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, concurrency

If I have a multi-million row table and I run a transaction that updates 50k rows, what are the performance implications of this?

Assuming it's indexed correctly, it shouldn't take long, but what rows are locked and how is the usage of that table affected?

1. Are rows being updated during the transaction able to be read
   after the transaction starts and before it finishes?
2. Are rows not being updated during
   the transaction able to be read after the transaction starts and before it finishes?
3. If another transaction starts trying to change rows that are being changed by
   a previously unfinished transaction, will that transaction fail at
   start or after it tries to commit (assuming conflict)?

My question is for Postgres 9.3; I assume there are variations.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/explicit-locking.html#LOCKING-TABLES - it is not substantially different from newer versions, at least not regarding your questions.  For the third one, https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/transaction-iso.html which is - I think - basically the same ever since.  Also, please consider upgrading to a newer version as 9.3 is out of support since last month.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Are rows being updated during the transaction able to be read after the transaction starts and before it finishes?

Yes, in Postgres reads do not block writes and writes do not block reads. The [Postgres documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/mvcc-intro.html) states that:

> Internally, data consistency is maintained
>   by using a multiversion model (Multiversion Concurrency Control,
>   MVCC). This means that while querying a database each transaction sees
>   a snapshot of data (a database version) as it was some time ago,
>   regardless of the current state of the underlying data. […] The main
>   advantage of using the MVCC model of concurrency control rather than
>   locking is that in MVCC locks acquired for querying (reading) data do not
>   conflict with locks acquired for writing data, and so reading never
>   blocks writing and writing never blocks reading.

#### Are rows not being updated during the transaction able to be read after the transaction starts and before it finishes?

Yes.

#### If another transaction starts trying to change rows that are being changed by a previously unfinished transaction, will that transaction fail at start or after it tries to commit (assuming conflict)?

This depends on the [Transaction Isolation Level](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/transaction-iso.html) and if you are issuing a write that depends on a read or a blind write. Using the default level *Read Committed* the second transaction has to wait until the first transaction is done writing. In higher transaction levels one of the transactions might get aborted with a serialization error.

You can actually try this yourself by running two `psql` sessions:

Session 1:

```
-- first set up a table
CREATE TABLE tools (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, description STRING);
INSERT INTO tools(description) VALUES('scredriver');
INSERT INTO tools(description) VALUES('hammer');

-- now type the following into two psql sessions
          SESSION 1             |          SESSION 2
                                |
BEGIN TRANSACTION;              |
UPDATE tools                    |
   SET description = 'anvil'    |
 WHERE id = 1;                  |
                                | BEGIN TRANSACTION;
                                |UPDATE tools
                                |   SET description = 'wrench'
                                | WHERE id = 1;
                                |-- this transaction is blocked
                                |-- until the other transaction
COMMIT TRANSACTION;             |-- commits
```

As you will see, session 2 will get blocked by session 1. Only if session 1 commits, session 2 will be able to continue.

The postgres documentation also contains [performance suggestions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/transaction-iso.html#XACT-SERIALIZABLE) on how to avoid blocking and serialization failures when using higher transaction levels.

Comment: If the transaction is accumulating data, I assume it would have to write somewhere. I could see why that obviously would need a "Multi-Version", but for reads alone, I'm not sure why the transaction couldn't read the true underlying data; since there's no writes, wouldn't it be safe? I've never had to do c-level concurrency. When you say "locks", are you referring to mutexes? And if so, would doubling the cache or duplicating data allow for more resource or semaphores, could that improve performance for the third case ("depends on a read or a blind write")? This is a little over my head btw.

Answer (score 3):

1 Yes

rows being updated can be read and will show the old value until the transaction is committed.

2 yes

rows not being written are unaffected.

3 no or yes depending.

If the other transaction holds a lock that this one needs a deadlock will be clared and one of the transactions cancelled else the other transaction will be halted until this one commits or rolls-back. and at that stage it will exit with an error or be allowed to continue.

For this reason long-lived transdactions are best kept to a minimum.

Comment: About 1, the old value is shown when the isolation level is REPEATABLE READ or SERIALIZABLE; when the isolation level is READ COMMITTED, the new value is shown (when the other transaction is committed).